# Different result Encrypt C# Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption

When I try to convert code form Java to C#, i have a big problem with EncryptFunction.
I have this code in Java:

```
    private String KEY_PRIVATE_HP = "__hpcSecretKey__";

    private IvParameterSpec getIvParameterSpec() {
        byte[] empty = new byte[16];
        return new IvParameterSpec(empty);
    }

    private String encryptBin(String value) {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_PRIVATE_HP.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, getIvParameterSpec());

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

And i converted it to C# like that:

```
        static string  KEY_PRIVATE_HP = "__hpcSecretKey__";

        public static string encryptBin(string value)
        {
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KEY_PRIVATE_HP);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length));
        }
```

But when i debug in C# and Java together, it have different result.
What's wrong?

Comment: You are using PKCS5 in Java and PKCS7 in C#.

Comment: @iakovosGurulian Those are [the same](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding)

Comment: The IV is not set in JAVA.

Comment: @kelalaka can i remove or set IV same with Java in C#?

Comment: Normally, as Maarten noted, the salt must be generated randomly and usually prepended to ciphertext. You can set but you have it manually. AFAIK, you are trying to C# to Java and Java to C#. Better first try encrypted Java and Decrypt in C#, then v.s. So that, you can extract the prepended IV form the ciphertext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one code you are using an all zero byte IV, in the other you copy the key bytes.

Both are insecure, for CBC mode the IV should be unpredictable; usually secure random values are used and prefixed to the ciphertext.

You may want to have a look at authenticated ciphers such as GCM. Using CBC between two programs for transport security is insecure.

Comment: I want to change code in C#, i try to set rijndaelCipher.IV = new byte[0x00] but it go to Exception: Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm. How can i fix?

Comment: You need 16 bytes (the block size in bytes) of zeros. `new byte[0x00]` creates a zero length (or empty) byte array. Note that you can use back-ticks `\`code\`` to indicate inline code.

Comment: I'm not clearly, what exactly i will do? Because the first time i code with Encrypt

Comment: Well, `new byte[16]` possibly? C# arrays are initialized to zero.